# Bash variable variables passed through functions

Tags: bash, shell

I've looked over a couple other variable variable posts here but still seem stuck with what I'm trying to attempt.

I have an existing script that has a series of similar block like

```
set_name="something"

# Required values
var1=$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "key1_${set_name}")
if [[ -z "$var1" ]]; then
    echo "Cannot find required var1"
    exit 1
fi
var2=$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "key2_${set_name}")
if [[ -z "$var2" ]]; then
    echo "Cannot find required var2"
    exit 1
fi
# Optional, okay to be empty
var3=$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "key3_${set_name}")
var4=$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "key4_${set_name}")
```

I was trying to factor some of the boilerplate checks out to keep this set of lookups assignment easier to read (in my opinion anyway).  The last iteration I had attempted (clearly not working) looks like

```
ZTest () {
    var=$1
    if [[ -z "${!var}" ]]; then
        echo $2
        exit 1
    fi
}

VarRequire () {
    var=$1
    key=$2
    errmsg=$3
    VarLookup ${!var} $key
    ZTest ${!var} $errmsg
}

VarLookup () {
    var=$1
    key=$2
    ${!var}=$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "$key")
}

# Required 
VarRequire "var1" "key1_${set_name}" "Cannot find required var1"
VarRequire "var2" "key2_${set_name}" "Cannot find required var2"

# optional 
VarLookup "var3" "key3_${set_name}"
VarLookup "var4" "key4_${set_name}"
```

The end result is I would be able to reference $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4 down the line in the script just the same as the original.

Is what I'm attempting possible in bash?

Comment: you can use `local` qualifier to limit the scope of function variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZTest` is already available as a parameter expansion operator:

```
: ${var1:?Cannot find required var1}
```

You are close with `VarLookup`, though; you need to use the `declare` command to create the variable. `${!var}` is only for accessing the value once the variable exists. (Note that `declare` requires the `-g` option to avoid creating a local variable, and that option was only introduced in version 4.2.)

```
VarLookup () {
  local var=$1
  local key=$2
  declare -g "${var}=$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "$key")"
}
```

Prior to version 4.2, you can use `printf` in place of `declare`:

```
printf -v "$var" '%s' "$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "$key")"
```

---

I would resist the urge to refactor *too* much in shell, as indirection can be fragile. I'd suggest something more direct like

```
var_lookup () {
    REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "${1}_$set_name"
}

var1=$(var_lookup key1); : ${var1:?Cannot find required var1}
var2=$(var_lookup key2); : ${var2:?Cannot find required var2}
var3=$(var_lookup key3)
var4=$(var_lookup key4)
```

Comment: In a function, `declare` == `local`, need `-g`

Comment: I wasn't able to get your printf version working for what ever reason but last option seemed good enough for me

Answer (score 2):

Too much indirection in the Var* functions

```
VarRequire () {
    local var=$1
    local key=$2
    local errmsg=$3
    VarLookup "$var" "$key"
    ZTest "$var" "$errmsg"
}

VarLookup () {
    local var=$1
    local key=$2
    declare -g "$var"="$(REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere mybinary -p "$key")"
}
```

The `declare` command allows you to use a variable's value as the variable name. I use the `-g` option so the variable is global.

The ZTest function does require the indirection.

Answer (score 0):

From the BASH manpage

> ```
>    local [option] [name[=value] ...]
>           For  each  argument,  a local variable named name is created,
>           and assigned value.  The option can be any of the options
>           accepted by declare.  When local is used within a function, it
>           causes the variable name to have a visible scope restricted to 
>           that function and its children.  With no operands, local writes a
>           list of local variables  to the  standard  output.   It is an
>           error to use local when not within a function.  The return status
>           is 0 unless local is used outside a function, an invalid name is
>           supplied, or name is a readonly variable.
> ```

So the answer is yes. If you declare a variable a `local` within a function, and it calls another function, that function has access to the variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `REQUIRED_ENV_VAR=/path/to/somewhere` once at the start?
And have your mybinary return 0 when a var is found?

You might like something like

```
function mylog {
   errortype=$1
   shift
   echo "(maybe show ${errortype}) $*"
   if [ "$errortype" = "error" ]; then
      exit 1
   fi
}

var1=$(mybinary -p "key1_${set_name}") || mylog error "Cannot find required var1"
var2=$(mybinary -p "key2_${set_name}") || mylog error "Cannot find required var2"
var3=$(mybinary -p "key3_${set_name}") 
var4=$(mybinary -p "key4_${set_name}") || mylog debug "Just want to say something"
```